# ...Capital letter after period(s)?

Tags: punctuation, capitalization, commas, periods

Excuse my terrible English knowledge, but I have been wondering this for some time already:
What is correct for the next phrase?:

> And he was there. alone. sad. and crying...

or

> And he was there. Alone. Sad. And crying...

or

> And he was there, alone, sad and crying...

On the first and second cases, I use periods for separating the state of the subject. For some reason, I like it to give better suspense. Given the way I am using the periods, should I use Capital letters after them, or not? These periods are pretty much like commas...

... But maybe I am terribly wrong and should never use periods for such purpose? Should I always follow the third case? Just using commas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would write the first word after the period in capital case, as you did in the second sentence you wrote.
The general rule of writing a word in capital case after a period is still valid even if you write a single word and then a period.

In those cases, the periods are used to give an emphasis to the single words. The pause when "reading" a period is longer than the pause used for a comma; for this reason I would not say the periods are like commas, in the examples you wrote.

Comment: Using periods instead of commas is something that should be done in specific cases, to give more emphasis; if you keep doing it in all the sentences, the emphasis is lost, and the sentences you write would be seen as not correct.

Comment: Hmm.... do I have to use capital case after suspensive dots as well? (haha, forgot how they're called in English, sorry)

Comment: @Omega Do you mean ellipsis ... like you used in your comment? And I'd say, no BTW.

Comment: But why should we start our sentences with capital letters? What's the philosophy behind it?

Comment: @aminabzz That's done in all the languages I know. If there is a "philosophy" behind it, it's not about English.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Correction: all the languages that have separated letters.

Comment: @aminabzz No, all the languages that use capital case and lower case, which is the case for all the languages I know. Latin spoken from ancient Romans isn't included in the languages I know.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Some languages don't use capital and lower cases. For example, looking at Arabic and Persian, the letters are attached to each other in words; like سلام which is created from letters س ل ا م. We have capital and lower cases if the words are created from separated letters like in English itself.

Comment: @aminabzz _All the languages I know._ doesn't mean _All the languages spoken on Earth._ I know some languages don't have capital case and lower case. Also, _separated letters_ (as you said) is the case for all the languages: All the languages use more than a letter. (_Separated letters_ doesn't mean _capital case and lower case_.)

Comment: @kiamlaluno I don't talk about separated letters _alphabetically_. I'm saying that in some languages words are made without attaching the letters to each other (so in these languages words are made of separated letters); like in English. Do you see, for example, in the word "water" the "w" and "a" attached to each other? But in some languages, like Persian, the words are made of attached letters. For example, in the word "خرمالو" the "خ" letter is attached to "ر". If Persian words were made of separated letters, it would be "خ ر م ا ل و". You didn't understand my "separated letters" well.

Answer (score 3):

I try to avoid starting a sentence with the word "and".

> … he was there. Alone. Sad. And crying.

If using stops instead of commas for greater emphasis I would remove the second "and" as it suggests the final element of a list separated by commas: "a, b, c and d".

> … he was there. Alone. Sad. Crying.

To me that has greater emphasis and avoids starting a sentence with a conjunction.

You can also use an em-dash for pauses in a sentence — though this is rarer.